# Correct image path to display image properly on front-end in Express React (create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, image, express, path

The answer to this problem is probably very simple, I hope.

So I'm creating an app based on MongoDB, Node, Express, React and so on, but I can't figure out how to properly setup and display user's avatar after he uploads it.

I have a ready API endpoint for uploading avatar, which when hit with request successfully uploads an image. (with multer middleware help) I'm also storing it in MongoDB properly. The thing is it currently looks like this and I'm pretty sure it shouldn't:

In Redux state:

```
avatar(pin): "C:\Users\Kuba\Desktop\mern_project\client\public\avatars\uploads\profileAvatar-1558374898723.jpeg"
```

So how should the path to uploaded image look like so I can successfully display it in React (built with create-react-app if that's of any help). In which folder should I store uploaded images?

That is my default avatar path which works pretty well, but it was simply implemented by import in React component.

```
avatar(pin): "/static/media/template-avatar2.173d1842.svg"
```

[Project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yLRh.png)

Client is the frontend, API endpoint in routes/api/profile.js

I appreciate any help.

Below is the route

```
  router.post(
  "/avatar",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  upload.single("avatar"),
  (req, res) => {
    const errors = {};

// Path to the avatar is in req.file.path
if (!req.file.path) {
  errors.avatar = "Wrong file format";
  return res.status(404).json(errors);
}
const avatarPath = req.file.path;

Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
  .then(profile => {
    if (profile) {
      Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
        { user: req.user.id },
        { $set: { avatar: avatarPath } },
        { new: true }
      )
        .then(profile => {
          res.json(profile);
        })
        .catch(err => res.json(err));
    } else {
      errors.noprofile = "Couldn't find the profile";
      res.status(404).json(errors);
    }
    errors.noprofile = "Couldn't find the profile";
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json(errors));
```

}
);

Multer settings

```
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./client/src/img/uploads/avatars");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + file.filename + "." + file.mimetype.slice(6)
    );
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png")
    cb(null, true);
  else {
    // reject a file
    let errors = {};
    cb(
      new Error(
        (errors.avatar = "Wrong filetype, only png and jpg types are eligible")
      ),
      false
    );
  }
};

// Upload avatar middleware
const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2
  },
  fileFilter
});
```

EDIT: Okay I changed the path in Multer to relative one, looks like this now, still doesn't work.

```
avatar(pin): "client\src\img\uploads\avatars\avatar-undefined.png"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved this so I'm posting the answer in case someone has the same problem.

Solution is kinda stupid actually but it works so...

Apparently in order to get images to show in create-react-app they must be stored in "client/public" and that's where the root directory starts.

So I changed the destination directory in multer to:

```
"./client/public/images/uploads/avatars"
```

And since the root directory starts with public, the path had to start with "/images/..." in my case. So I simply cut the first 15 characters - the whole "./client/public", before storing it in database.